# Derivative of $3 \cdot sin(2x)$

Tags: derivatives

Is the derivative of  $3 \cdot sin(2x)$

$3 \cdot [cos(2x) \cdot 2]$ or $3\cdot [cos(2x)]\cdot 2$?

I'm unsure about this technicality.
The first one seems more reasonable to me.

Comment: Both derivatives you gave are equal to $6\cos(2x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that $$a \cdot (b \cdot c) = (a \cdot b) \cdot c = a \cdot b \cdot c = a \cdot c \cdot b$$ and so on. Laws of multiplication.

Therefore $3[\cos(2x) \cdot 2] = 3 \cdot \cos(2x) \cdot 2 = 6 \cdot \cos (2x)$

Answer (score 0):

Both of then are correct

$ 6 \cdot \cos (2x) = 3\cdot [\cos(2x) \cdot 2] = 3 \cdot \cos(2x) \cdot 2 $